# how to work with multiple database

Tags: php

I am working on one company internal web software and in this I have given forum option for internal employee.Now I have to add second company to forum so that second company employee can also give some comment in forum.I have two database one for my company internal and second is second company database.

Please Help me how can I Implement this???

Comment: first, create 2 connections to db server. second, change the code to read/write to both (or just one, depends on the case) for every action against the db.

Comment: But how can I maintain which user post the comment.....cause I have two database and both database have different user table???And I have to show all comments made by all users from both database to each and every users.

Comment: i c what u'r facing: 2 users in different tables have the same ID. OK, then, instead of using the field "id" to identify a user, use something like $Table.$User_Id

Answer (score 1):

Always use resource returned by `mysql_connect()` so you know what database you use

```
// database 1
$db1 = mysql_connect();
// database 2
$db2 = mysql_connect();

// query db1
mysql_query($query,$db1);
```

Also try reading the [docs](http://php.net/mysql_connect) about it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what database you are using..,,

and try to read some mysql function cause theres a function for linking databases..

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 (3, 4, 5 ...) db connections.

If your bases is not MySql only, you can use PDO extension:

```
$db1 = new PDO($param1, $param2, $param3);
$db2 = new PDO($param4, $param5, $param6);
```

And then you can use **any** of them, e.g.:

```
$db2->exec();
```